# Xcode: difference in commenting with '///' or '//!' regarding documentation

Tags: xcode, documentation, comments

In *Xcode*, if you prepend a one line comment starting with `///` or `//!` (`/**` and `/*!` for multi-line ones) to a method declaration, it shows it within *Quick Help* (e.g., `Option Click` on the method name).

Is there any difference between these? Can somebody point at where this is documented on Apple's Developer website?

Comment: Are you referring to HeaderDoc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Xcode HeaderDoc support is documented in [Mac Developer Library - HeaderDoc Tags](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/HeaderDoc/tags/tags.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001215-CH346-CHDJFEGF).

The document has not been updated since 2013, but it does show the supported comment syntax: `/*!` and the supported `@` tags, etc.  Three slashes `///` is just another way to do in-line block documentation.

`///` and `//!` are not documented on the HeaderDoc Tags page.  It is possible these were added in Xcode 5.  The [changelog](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/WhatsNewXcode/Articles/xcode_5_0.html) states:

> Project documentation from framework API reference documentation and structured comments in your own source code are displayed in the quick help panel and in code completion popover views. Doxygen and HeaderDoc structured comments are supported formats.

Comment: Excellent answer, that's just what I wanted to know.